# TypeError: invalid color argument on python

Tags: python

This is my code:

```
import pygame
import numpy as np
import random

line = open('clothes.txt', 'r').readlines()
colourCode = np.array(line[1])

s = pygame.Surface((50,50)) 
s.set_alpha(200)
s.fill(colourCode)
```

The file is

```
1
(0,0,0)
3
4
5
```

It returns `TypeError: invalid color argument` but I don't know why :( 
It works when I put the array directly into `s.fill()` but not with the file import

Answer (score 0):

You need to have `(0, 0, 0)` as a `tuple`, and not as a `np.array()`.

You can use `ast.literal_eval` :

```
import pygame
import numpy as np
import random

import ast

line = open('clothes.txt', 'r').readlines()

colourCode = ast.literal_eval(line[1])
print(colourCode, type(colourCode))
# (0, 0, 0) <class 'tuple'>

s = pygame.Surface((50,50)) 
s.set_alpha(200)
s.fill(colourCode)
```

Answer (score 0):

the `fill()` method wants a tuple, not an numpy array. And you have to parse the line first:

```
colourCode = (int(part) for part in line[1][1:-1].split(","))
```

You may have to do some validation before, depending on where the file is from.